# How to Visualise large number of code in Pro-B

Tags: formal-methods, event-b

I have a problem with visualising large number of code in [ProB](http://stups.hhu.de/ProB/).
This graph shows the login section of a server with (using Graphviz' dotty) of ProB, but there is no solution for large number of code to get the graph.
Please let me know your suggestions and ideas,[image: Screenshot of ProB showing the current state]

[image: State space visualization]

Comment: What do you mean by "large number of code"? And by "no solution"? What did you do when no solution had been found?